# Error: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist (pt2) am new to python btw

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help with creating a button with an image, the creation of the image seems to not be a problem as when I hover over the file location of the image, the image pops up. However, the error image "pyimage1" doesn't exist shows up as seen in the screenshots. This is for a cookie clicker type game for a school project and I am very knew to Python (3 days of learning so far). Importing OS and using OS.cwd() isn't effective because the file path is correct.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

from Game import Game

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Clicking Mania")
gui.geometry("600x600")

# Inside GUI title
title = Label(gui, text="Clicking Mania")
title.pack()
title.grid_location(3, 2)

# Images
os.getcwd()
image = PhotoImage(file='../GameImages/DPic.png')
imagelabel = Label(image=image)
imageshop = PhotoImage(file='../GameImages/upgrade.png')
imageupgrade = Label(image=imageshop)

# Buttons
pickaxebutton = Button(gui, image=image, command=Game.clickcmd(1), borderwidth=0)
pickaxebutton.pack(pady=100)
upgradebutton = Button(gui, image=imageshop, borderwidth=0)

# change image
up1button = Button(gui, image=image, command=Game.up1cmd(), borderwidth=0)

balance = Label(gui, text="Balance: ", padx=20, pady=10)
balance.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

```
class Game():
    multiplier = 0

    global upgrades
    upgrades = ["2","4","6","8","10"],["Upgrade 1", "Upgrade 2", "Upgrade 3", "Upgrade 4", "Upgrade 5"]



    def setMultiplier(x):
        multiplier = x
        print(multiplier)


    def clickcmd(multiplier):
        global clicks
        clicks += 1 * (multiplier)
        return clicks



    def up1cmd(x):
        setMultiplier(upgrades[0][x])





    # x = Which upgrade was bought, returns upgrade[x]
    def getUpgrade(x):
        return upgrades[0,x] , upgrades[1,x]
```

Comment: On exactly which line does the error occur?

Comment: pickaxebutton = Button(gui, image=image, command=Game.clickcmd(1), borderwidth=0), The line with this.

Comment: Note that `command=-Game.clicked(1)` and `command=Game.upload()` are both wrong.  In both cases, you are CALLING that function immediately, and passing whatever they return to the `Button`.  You need `command=Game.upload`, and you'll have to use a lambda for the other: `command=lambda: return Game.clicked(1)`.

Comment: The problem has to be the path.  When you printed `os.cwd()`, what did you see?  Are you running this from a command line?  You're sure the images are one level up and then down?

Comment: Before I added the image, imageshop the image, image2 had shown the correct image. I am using PyCharm on Jetbrains I believe and when I hovered over the file location, it shows the image. With the os.cwd() , I wasn't able to print anything, I changed command in the "pickaxebutton" into what you recommended, and it said there was a syntax error. pickaxebutton = Button(gui, image=image2, command=lambda:return Game.clickcmd(1), borderwidth=0)

Comment: My fault, remove the word `return` from that.  I know better.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems in your `Game` class that you haven't found yet.  Two-dimensional arrays in Python are not indexed as `[a,b]` -- it has to be `[a][b]`.  You don't use `global` with class variables.  And you must use `self` to access object variables.  And it looks like you expect to use the first list as integers, so you need to make them integers.  Note that a dictionary would probably be a better choice for `upgrades`:

```
class Game:
    multiplier = 0
    clicks = 0
    upgrades = [2,4,6,8,10],["Upgrade 1", "Upgrade 2", "Upgrade 3", "Upgrade 4", "Upgrade 5"]

    def setMultiplier(self, x):
        self.multiplier = x
        print(self.multiplier)

    def clickcmd(self, multiplier):
        self.clicks += multiplier
        return self.clicks

    def up1cmd(self, x):
        self.setMultiplier(self.upgrades[0][x])

    # x = Which upgrade was bought, returns upgrade[x]
    def getUpgrade(self, x):
        return self.upgrades[0][x] , self.upgrades[1][x]
```

Comment: Another side note, I wrote this assuming you want to create a "game" object to hold your state.  Your current code seems to be using `Game` as a namespace, not as an object.  That's not a design I prefer.